# How to show elements in a table row that are not combinable ? ( Pls see description)

Tags: tables, icons, error-message

I am having issue with a current project. We have a table which shows "offers" and also these offers would be applicable to mobile numbers labelled as : Number 1, Number 2 etc as you shown in this image. [image]

*Now some of these offers can be unstackable or cannot be combined together. For this use case , let's say **Offer A** is unstackable with **Offer B** & **Offer C**. Suppose Offer A is accepted for Number 1 & Number 2, then these numbers would show unstackable for Offer B for same lines. So visually we will have to show the selected lines " Number 1 , Number 2" cannot be selected for Offer B & C. **I tried to show the unstackable lines with a warning icon to differentiate from other numbers as shown below:** ([Prototype link](https://www.figma.com/proto/40FzyFHVjNe9QXcwUyRDTl/Design-resources?type=design&node-id=101-8&t=x3a2YrPSeI0sYHAI-1&scaling=min-zoom&page-id=28%3A2&starting-point-node-id=101%3A8&mode=design))
[image]

But I still feel this can be solved in better ways. Is having icon enough to point out that these lines are not stackable or it gets lost in the visual salience. Please if anyone has any ideas to make this better do suggest. Favourite answer will get a coffee from me. :P

Comment: Shouldn't the accept button be disabled?

Comment: If you mean the Offer B should be disabled. Only for Numbers 1 & 2 , it cannot br selected. It should still apply to rest of numbers, so it cannot be shown disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the distribution of items in each of the cells:

- If the telephones are options, why do they appear in the description that it's a fixed element?
- What's the meaning of the <kbd>Reject</kbd> button?
- Is the alert necessary?
- Is it necessary to repeat the alert?

The first thing that occurs to me is to try to clean up the information, leaving the description of the offer on one side and relegating the selectable elements to the action, for example in a multi-select dropdown menu where only active items can be selected.

[image]

Comment: Hi, the numbers are shown against each offer to denote which numbers applicable to which offers. All these numbers might be under same account holder. Think of like being on a family plan. Reject button tells the system user is not interested in the offer and not to suggest these again. Alert is there just to denote that offer A might not be stackable with offer B. So which ever lines Offer A is applied on, cannot be selected for B.